# Running a console app from the Umbraco backend

Tags: umbraco

I have been charged with making a C# console application to do a daily migration of an Umbraco site from a developer site to a live site. The console application works like a charm, but the customer wants a button in the Umbraco backend where they could force the migration instead of waiting for the daily execution.

My question is this:
How would one go about making such a button. Is it possible to run a console application from the Umbraco backend or would I have to make it into a user control? Any help would be appreciated, and if you need more information just write a comment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of a way to run a console application from the Umbraco interface.

Possible solution:

Can the console application simply run every 10 minutes and check a value in the database?  If the value is true, then do the migration and reset the value.  This could be a date as well.

Then in Umbraco simply make a dashboard .aspx page with a button that says "Go Live" and that sets the flag in the DB to true.

Make sense?

Comment: I have considered this solution myself, but they want to be able to do force a migration "instantly". What I am trying to do now is make a dashboard user control that simply references the code in my console app and calls the Main method. Is gonna be interesting to see if it works.

Comment: Yea, I'm guessing you can probably do most of this in a dashboard page.  The only issue might be if its a long running process.

Comment: Turns out that it actually works. :P The running time is only around 12 seconds for doing it, so doing all the work on the dashboard page worked out just fine.

Comment: I am gonna accept this answer because the comments most reflects the correct answer :)

Answer (score 0):

This is my idea. I am not sure whether its correct or not . Please go through it.

In umbraco we can create a macro by using Asp.Net user controls. So in that macro put a button and in that button click i think we can execute the console application.